# Keyboard shortcut issues

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Until recently, I've been able to use Command + ',' as a subscript shortcut on Google Drive. However, when I try to use it now, it sends me to the Firefox preferences page. Any ideas on how to get it back to working as the subscript shortcut?

Comment: Which OS? Do you mean to say that this command while Google Drive was opened in the browser window? Have you checked to see Firefox added this shortcut?

Comment: I'm using a MacBook. I tried using the shortcut with Google Drive open in a Safari tab, it sent me to the page telling me that Safari isn't my default browser.